# Xamarin Forms App fails installing APK in Release mode?

Tags: c#, parsing, apk

Has anyone ever encountered an app that can install APKs in Debug mode but fails to do so in Release Mode as well as when Archived and properly Singed? With the error message "There was a problem parsing the package"?

I am able to install other APKs from the web as well as to get the Android Update Window for my App in Debug Mode (I cannot actually update the app since the debug and release configuration conflict). However, when in Release Mode or Archived and Signed the packages I download are not recognized at all, even from other vendors.

I'll try to clear up the confusion. Let's say you give me an APK that works perfectly, the Facebook apk for example. If I ask my app to download the apk with a Dropbox link and install it with an Intent in Debug mode it will install successfully! If I do this in Release Mode it will fail with the error of parsing the package. It doesnt matter which APK I download. The package installation fails only in Release! This is why logcat wouldn't help me, it's not the APKs fault, it's the procedure of installing the APK.

```
            //Download Package 
            string installPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Plugin.XF.AppInstallHelper.InstallationHelper.GetPublicDownloadPath(), "facebook.apk");
            using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                var hcResponse = await hc.GetAsync(apkLink);
                var byteArray = await hcResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(installPath, byteArray);
            }

            // Create an intent to the settings page to allow installation of unknown apps
            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageUnknownAppSources);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName));
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            // Install the APK file using an intent
            var installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            var file = new Java.IO.File(installPath);
            file.SetReadable(true, false);
            var apkUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "com.*hidden*.fileprovider", file);
            installIntent.SetDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            installIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(installIntent);
```

So this code works as expected in Debug Mode but fails in Release Mode!

Comment: Install the APK file via adb using `adb install your.apk` and you will get a more detailed error message what is wrong with the APK.

Comment: @Robert the APKs install fine manually, as well as in Debug Mode. The problem is that it is unable to update itself

Comment: How do you sign your app? Is this all happening on the same phone or are we talking about different phones? Which Android version(s) is installed on the involved phones?

Comment: I am signing using Ad Hoc successfully since my previews method of updating was working flawlessly. Yes this on the same tablet. I run Debug Mode in VS and everything works as expected, when switching to Release Mode the "There is a problem parsing the package".

Comment: The main problem is that you don't have a detailed error message. Have you checked `logcat` while the installation fails if it displays anything related to the app installation? Without more details it is unlikely you will get an answer here...

Comment: I'll try to clear up the confusion. Let's say you give me an APK that works perfectly, the Facebook apk for example. If I ask my app to download the apk with a Dropbox link and install it with an Intent in Debug mode it will install successfully!  If I do this in Release Mode it will fail with the error of parsing the package. It doesnt matter which APK I download. The package installation fails only in Release! This is why logcat wouldn't help me, it's not the APKs fault, it's the procedure of installing the APK.